# Group or collapse columns in Power BI Like Excel (to save screen spaced)

Tags: excel, powerbi, visualization, powerbi-desktop

I'm using a table visualisation object in Excel to produce a report. This report used to be in Excel and it has a large number of columns (fields). In Excel this is handled easily by column grouping so that you can collapse or expand columns (if you wanted to see less or more). This ensures there is no excessive scrolling to the right hand-side in Excel.

I was wondering if it was possible to replicated this effect in Power BI visuals either using a table or a matrix?

I've searched around the internet and I'm not hopeful that this is possible.

Suggestions welcomed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can but they work differently. e.g.

I have a levels table like this which I want to expand and collapse:

[image]

If I add the following columns to a matrix field well, they will look like this:

[image]

[image]

You can then click on the expand (drill down) and collapse (drill up) buttons on the top of the matrix to look like this:

[image]

e.g. 1

[image]

e.g. 2

[image]

e.g. 3

[image]

Comment: Thanks @David Bacci. Very useful to know :)